# Cloning a repository and building with Gradle

Tags: git, properties, gradle, settings, credentials

I've just got access to a repository on Bitbucket, company based, and now I need to clone the repository, and then work with on Android Studio, all running on Win7.

The instructions I was given was to install Gradle, and then clone the repository using the "clone gitxxxxx" command. I tried running the command on terminal/powershell and it said "command git not found", so I installed Git.

When I ran it, I could clone the repository, but on the last step, "gradle assembleBeta", it bombs out by saying something about credentials.

I was given a set of credentials (mavenUser/mavenPassword) and told to put this in my "local gradle.properties" folder. I've searched high and low, looked through tons of threads, and I still haven't found anything to help me find where to put these credentials file.

I know it's supposed to be in the "/.gradle/gradle.properties:" file, but where is this file? I found a .gradle folder in my documents folder, but no gradle.properties file.

I'm not sure if my intial setup is to blame or etc, but when I tested everything (Android Studio, Gradle, Git) everything seemed fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the `gradle.properties` file in the `.gradle` folder. The location of this folder  can be configured by altering the environment variable `GRADLE_USER_HOME`. This will be where all external dependencies are cached locally, and where your builds will be stored when you run `gradle install`.

Inside your file, you should have the following:

```
mavenUser=userNameProvided
mavenPassword=passwordProvided
```

Any properties added to the gradle.properties file applies to every gradle project. You can also add project specific gradle.properties files by putting them at the root of your gradle project. More details can be found here:
https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Comment: how do i create the file specifically?                                                                               Also, do i just copy and paste the credentials into that file? e.g. mavenUser=usernameetc
mavenPassword=apsswordetc

Comment: @nevadayz just go into your .gradle folder and then create a file as you would any other file? I always do the following: right click, new text document, then when you get to choose the name of the file, change the .txt extension to .properties. Then edit with notepad, or notepad++, or any tool like that, and add your above credentials. I have edited my answer to show how the key value pairs should look.

Comment: @nevadayz I have added a little more information around what the gradle.properties file is for.

Comment: awesome! so I've added the properties file in, and it progressed one step further in the build, but eventually still crashed. However, this only really made a difference if i put the file in the same file as my project, shouldnt it be in the ".gradle" folder? Also, do i need to make any amendments with the build.gradle file?

Comment: @nevadayz Glad you've got a bit further. Go to your environment variables and see where `GRADLE_USER_HOME` is currently pointing to. If it's not pointing anywhere, set it to a location of your choice, and then put the `gradle.properties` file in there. I have the exact same setup on my machine so know this works. No changes needed to the build.gradle file. :)